# Monitor the cost of a S3 bucket with nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to create S3 buckets on demand and monitor their cost.
As everybody knows, the Amazon's API is wonderful, so I'm kind of stuck to a point.

Here is what I'm doing in few steps

I create a Bucket

```
s3.createBucket({
  Bucket: bucket,
  ACL: 'public-read',
}).promise();
```

And my first question is : **How do I (fully) enable cloudwatch on this bucket?**

My second question is: **Does anyone know how to completely compute the cost based on the metrics from CloudWatch?**

Then, I need to fetch some data from cloudwatch, something like weekly to evaluate the cost.

```
const date = new Date();
const StartTime = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
const EndTime = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);
const Period = Math.floor((EndTime.getTime() - StartTime.getTime()) / 1000);
cloudwatch
  .getMetricData({
    StartTime,
    EndTime,
    MetricDataQueries: [
      {
        Id: 'size',
        MetricStat: {
          Metric: {
            Dimensions: [
              {
                Name: 'StorageType',
                Value: 'StandardStorage',
              },
              {
                Name: 'BucketName',
                Value: 'my-bucket',
              },
            ],
            MetricName: 'BucketSizeBytes',
            Namespace: 'AWS/S3'
          },
          Period,
          Stat: 'Average',
          Unit: 'Bytes'
        },
        ReturnData: true,
      },
      {
        Id: 'count',
        MetricStat: {
          Metric: {
            Dimensions: [
              {
                Name: 'StorageType',
                Value: 'AllStorageTypes',
              },
              {
                Name: 'BucketName',
                Value: 'my-bucket',
              },
            ],
            MetricName: 'NumberOfObjects',
            Namespace: 'AWS/S3'
          },
          Period,
          Stat: 'Average',
          Unit: 'Count',
        },
        ReturnData: true,
      },
      {
        Id: 'downloaded',
        MetricStat: {
          Metric: {
            Dimensions: [
              {
                Name: 'FilterId',
                Value: 'EntireBucket',
              },
              {
                Name: 'BucketName',
                Value: 'my-bucket',
              },
            ],
            MetricName: 'BytesDownloaded',
            Namespace: 'AWS/S3'
          },
          Period,
          Stat: 'Average',
          Unit: 'Bytes'
        },
        ReturnData: true,
      },
    ],
  }, handleResponse);
```

Which returns me something like this

```
{
  "ResponseMetadata": {
    "RequestId": "588f3c78-bc39-11e8-a704-cbccb1b4e355"
  },
  "MetricDataResults": [
    {
      "Id": "size",
      "Label": "StandardStorage BucketSizeBytes",
      "Timestamps": [
        "2018-08-31T22:00:00.000Z"
      ],
      "Values": [
        1030
      ],
      "StatusCode": "Complete",
      "Messages": []
    },
    {
      "Id": "count",
      "Label": "AllStorageTypes NumberOfObjects",
      "Timestamps": [
        "2018-08-31T22:00:00.000Z"
      ],
      "Values": [
        3
      ],
      "StatusCode": "Complete",
      "Messages": []
    },
    {
      "Id": "downloaded",
      "Label": "EntireBucket BytesDownloaded",
      "Timestamps": [
        "2018-08-31T22:00:00.000Z"
      ],
      "Values": [
        1342
      ],
      "StatusCode": "Complete",
      "Messages": []
    }
  ]
}
```

And I don't have any other question, considering the AWS documentation, it was mostly to leave this code somewhere to help anybody that would pass by here...

Comment: Be aware that AWS already offers an S3 usage report: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/aws-usage-report.html

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, but my goal is to, daily, dynamically and automatically see the cost for each bucket. So downloading and parsing a CSV doesn't look really nice...

Comment: For enabling metrics collection, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/configure-metrics.html

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, and I used that for my tests, but now I want to enable it programmatically ;) I googled it also

Comment: I would think that you would call the putBucketMetricsConfiguration() method with the relevant configuration. If you add it from the console then you can list it with the API (or awscli) to see what was actually configured.

Comment: I tried to call the `getBucketMetricsConfiguration` and `listBucketMetricsConfigurations` on my actual manually configured bucket and the result is disappointing. The only result I get is `{"MetricsConfiguration": {"Id": "EntireBucket"}}`, so no way to find how to activate the good metrics... I'll try the put method with a bit of imagination, to see what it gives...